# props undefined despite setting it in the redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I get a strange error that concerns a reducer named **prs** for a given added or deleted person, in a nutshell this app allows to add or remove a person when clicked. each person has a random id.

First of all that's my parent component App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import PersonsComponent from './containers/PersonsComponent';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ol>
          <li>Turn this app into one which does NOT use local state (in components) but instead uses Redux</li>
        </ol>
        <PersonsComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The person component **(PersonsComponent.jsx)** is depicted as below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Person from "../components/Person/Person";
import AddPerson from "../components/AddPerson/AddPerson";

class PersonsComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    const { prs, personAddedHandler, personDeletedHandler } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <AddPerson personAdded={() => personAddedHandler(prs)} />
        {prs.map(person => (
          <Person
            key={person.id}
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            clicked={() => personDeletedHandler(prs, person.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonsComponent;
```

The **PersonComponent** container **(PersonsContainer.jsx)** that holds its props such as the **prs** reducer which means a given person, and the dispatchers actions **personAddedHandler** and **personDeletedHandler**:

```
import actions from './actions';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PersonsComponent from './PersonsComponent';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    prs: state.persons
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    personAddedHandler: persons => dispatch(actions.addPerson(persons)),
    personDeletedHandler: (persons, personId) =>
      dispatch(actions.deletePerson(persons, personId))
  };
};

const PersonsContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(PersonsComponent);

export default PersonsContainer;
```

Below our headache reducer **(reducer.jsx)**:

```
import types from "../constants/types";

const initialState = {
  persons: [
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: "Max",
      age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
    }
  ]
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_PERSON.type:
      return {
        ...state,
        persons: action.payload
      };
    case types.DELETE_PERSON.type:
      return {
        ...state,
        persons: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

And of course each reducer has its own action:

```
import types from "../constants/types";

export default {
  addPerson: (persons) => {
    const newPerson = {
      id: Math.random(), // not really unique but good enough here!
      name: "Max",
      age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
    };
    return {
      type: types.ADD_PERSON.type,
      payload: persons.concat(newPerson)
    };
  },
  deletePerson: (persons, personId) => ({
    type: types.DELETE_PERSON.type,
    payload: persons.filter(person => person.id != personId)
  })
};
```

But when I run my app with ***npm start*** I get the following error as screened below:

[image: props **prs** is undefined]

This error tells me that the store is likely not known (just a doubt, I'm not sure).

The redux store is still defined in **index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import reducer from './store/reducer';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks for your answer.

Comment: The error due to possibly prs is undefined or null so you can try to add condition prs && prs.length > 0

Comment: Please provide the code op `App.js` where you use the component

Comment: @Emanuele, check my edited question, the App.jsx is added

Comment: @please check the answer, it should be the fix of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is tat you are using the `PersonComponent`, that is not the wrapped one and does not have the `props` coming from Redux. Use the `PersonsContainer` insetead in you `App.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the variable is `undefined` and you are calling `map()` on that. The variable has to be an array, even if it is an empty one.

In React what you can do is using `&&` to prevent that error what you have.

Please find a possible solution:

```
{prs && prs.map(person => (
          <Person
            key={person.id}
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            clicked={() => personDeletedHandler(prs, person.id)}
          />
))}
```

In this way you are checking if `prs` does have a value and if it has then runs `map()` on that.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestion, but still the app is crashed, I get another error (personAddedHandler is not a function)  this fact confirm me that the store is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Please add condition to check null and length before binding

```
{prs && prs.length > 0 && (prs.map(person => (
          <Person
            key={person.id}
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            clicked={() => personDeletedHandler(prs, person.id)}
          />
        )))}
```

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestion, but still the app is crashed, I get another error (personAddedHandler is not a function) this fact confirm me that the store is not recognized.